# Doubt in row rank = column rank proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in \mathbb{F}^{m \times n}$. How do you prove that row rank of a matrix equals column rank ?

This is the question. Here is the proof posted on math stack exchange thread :

Let $A \in \mathbb{F}^{m \times n}$ and let $R = $[RREF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form#Reduced_row_echelon_form)$(A)$.

---

The non-zero rows of $R$ are obtained by invertible row operations on $A$. This means we can go back and forth between rows of $A$ and $R$. Therefore, non-zero rows of $R$ span $A$.Also, non-zero rows of $R$ are linearly independent(any dependent rows are reduced to $0$ rows). Therefore, **non-zero rows of $R$ form a basis for row space of $A$**.

**# of non-zero rows = # of leading $1$s in $R$ = dimension(row space of $A$) = row rank($A$)**

---

$R = EA$, where $E$ is an invertible [elementary matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix) product. Let $B = E^{-1}$.
Let $r_j$ be the $j$th pivot column of $R$.

$r_j$ = $E a_j \Rightarrow a_j = B r_j$. Since $r_j$ is a pivot column, $r_j=I_j$($j$ th column of identity matrix). Therefore, $a_j = B I_j$. Since columns of $I$ are independent, $a_j$s are independent(Proving this is easy -- start from definition of linear independence for $I_j$s and show that multiplication by $B$ does not affect the relationship). Therefore, **pivot columns of $A$ are linearly independent**.

Each non-pivot column of $R$ is linearly dependent on pivot columns of $R$(Otherwise, it would have been a pivot column). Since $a_j = B r_j$, each non-pivot column of $A$ is linearly dependent on pivot columns of $A$. Therefore, **pivot columns of $A$ span the column space of $A$**.

Therefore, **pivot columns of $A$ form a basis for column space of $A$**.

$\Rightarrow$ **column rank($A$) = dimension(col space($A$)) = # of pivot columns = # of leading $1$s in $R$ = row rank ($A$)**

[6chars]

My question is that in the paragraph

Each non-pivot column of $R$ is linearly dependent on pivot columns of $R$(Otherwise, it would have been a pivot column). Since $a_j = B r_j$, each non-pivot column of $A$ is linearly dependent on pivot columns of $A$. Therefore, **pivot columns of $A$ span the column space of $A$**.

How do we prove that each non-pivot column of $R$ is linearly dependent on pivot columns of $R$ implies that $a_j = Br_j$ so no-pivot columns of $A$ is linearly dependent on pivot columns of $A$?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: What did you try to prove it?

Comment: @ArcticChar I tried using the pivot in row echelon form theorems. So if the columns $c_1, c_2 \dots c_j$ contain a pivot in $R$, then for $a$, for each column $c_i$ will look like $(b_{1i} b_{2i} \dots b_{mi})^t$. Eventually, we will have $i$ variables and $m$ equations, but $m \geq i$ so we cannot be sure if there exists no pivot in the last column of row echelon form of $M$ where the first $i$ columns of $M$ are the $c_i$ and the last column is some other non pivot column of $A$.

If this is confusing, I would appreciate few hints (one or more) to help me get to the answer.

Comment: For example, if $r_4$ is a non-pivot column such that $r_4 = r_1 - 2r_3$ (say, $r_1, r_3$ are pivot columns). Then so is $a_4 = a_1 - 2a_3$.

Comment: @ArcticChar Got it. Thanks!